# Dynamic Paint and Cycles and Fire Simulation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, dynamic-paint, fire

Does Dynamic Paint work with Cycles and Fire Flow in the following way?

- Fire is moving as determined by Dynamic Paint Vertex Group
- Not just a single beginning frame of Vertex Group
- Cycles Render not Blender Internal Render.

---

If it does work, what are the practical settings in Blender?

[image]

**Additional Context**

I can see that the Weight Paint is successful in 3D View.

I cans see a successful Dynamic Paint with Fire with Blender Render.

This Blender User has Cycles with these results

Successful

- Particles which allow some movement with associated texture
- Full Mesh Fire
- Static Vertex Group
- Single Texture

Failed

- Image Sequence as Texture

Answer (score 1):

The mesh emitting flames is both a dynamic canvas and a smoke flow, it needs to use the same vertex group for painting and smoke flow.

[image]